# Flash object inside iframe didn't work in IE7-8

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, iframe

I have an iframe which loads page with following html inside it:

```
<object height="315" width="560">
  <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/VBBX9uJAy3A?version=3&hl=en_US">
  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
  <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
  <embed wmode="transparent" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/VBBX9uJAy3A?version=3&hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" height="315" width="560">
  <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
</object>
```

but when trying to open page in IE 7-8 browsed didn't display content. When I inspected page with developer tools I found that IE removes *embed* tag (the rest is ok). When accessing this page directly from browser (not from iframe) — everything works.

I can't abandon iframe due to security reasons.

I found the same problem at adobe's site, there are no answers. (http://forums.adobe.com/thread/183283)

Did anyone met this problem and know the solution?

Comment: could you tell for what security reasons you want to use an iframe? It doesn't seem like such a great idea to me..

Comment: This code (well, not particularly this one, any html-code, but this one is caused the problem) is provided by user, so it have to be located at different domain than application's domain.

Answer (score 0):

Is the youtube video a replacement example? If not, you should just use the embed tag provided by youtube itself:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/_4LYZC97hmM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: your way doesn't work in FF for me either. I suspect youtube blocks such ways for their own security reasons :)

Comment: Unfortunately no, this code may be not from youtube — it provided by user.

Comment: oh i see, so just the embeddable content that's provided by the user... I didn't quite get that from you last comment ;)